# TYPO3 sitemap with images?

Tags: sitemap, typo3

How can my Sitemap content element include images?

Comment: What kind of images? Please explain what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the answer

You can create a custom sitemap element which contains a HMENU

see link 
http://www.mail-archive.com/typo3-english@lists.netfielders.de/msg02403.html

a more complete example here
http://lauragavrila.blogspot.com/2010/04/blog-post.html